# Yamaguchi submersion theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let me remind first a theorem of Yamaguchi (1996).

Given $n\in \mathbb{N}, \mu_0>0$. Then there exist $\delta_n>0$ and $\epsilon_n(\mu_0)>0$ with the following property. Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional complete Alexandrov space with curvature $\geq -1$ and such that every point has an $(n,\delta_n)$-strainer of length at least $\mu_0$. Then if the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between $X$ and a complete Alexandrov space $M$ with curvature $\geq -1$ is less than $\epsilon_n(\mu_0)$, then there exists a $\tau(\delta_n,\epsilon_n(\mu_0))$-almost Lipschitz submersion $f\colon M\to X$. Here $\tau$ is a function satisfying $\lim_{\delta,\epsilon\to +0}\tau(\delta,\epsilon)=0$.

(Let me also remind for completeness the definition of $\epsilon$-almost submersion. For every $p,q\in M$ let $\theta$ denote the infimum of $\measuredangle qpx$ where $x\in f^{-1}(f(p))$. Then one has 
$$\big|\frac{|f(p)f(q)|}{|pq|}-\sin\theta\big|<\epsilon.)$$

*Yamaguchi says in his paper: "Because of the lack of differentiability in X, it is unclear at present if the map f
is actually a locally trivial fiber bundle. The author conjectures that this is true. In fact, in the case when both X and M have natural differentiable structures of class
$C^1$, we can take a locally trivial fibre bundle as the map f."*

**QUESTION. Is it known now, after 20 years, that the map $f$ may be chosen to be a locally trivial fiber bundle in general?**

Notice that the positive answer to the conjecture would imply that when $M$ and $X$ are compact, the Euler characteristic of $M$ is an integer multiple of the Euler characteristic of $X$. Is this known to be true?

Comment: I may not remember the whole story (which is why I won't post this as an answer) but I think the question is still open. I think Perelman proved log time ago that the map is a Serre fibration, so what you ask about the Euler characteristic is known. Some more recent references are http://www.sciencedirect.com.prx.library.gatech.edu/science/article/pii/S0001870812002058 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5919. Part of the issue is that a purely topological question of how to recognise a locally trivial fiber bundle is not completely resolved,

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Many thanks. May be Serre fibration property might be enough for some of my purposes. Unfortunately I failed to open your first link. Could you give more details on it?

Comment: The first link is "Stability of epsilon-Lipschitz and co-Lipschitz maps in Gromov–Hausdorff topology" by  Xiaochun Rong and Shicheng Xu. [Adv. in Math. Volume 231, Issue 2, 2012, 774–797]. The second link is a related paper by Xu at arxiv; I suspect you can open it.